# block completion status verification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am currently using enumerateObjectsUsingBlock block for enumerating under subviews, how can I figure out the completion of the block?

Below is the block content

```
[self.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

// The content
}];
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "the completion"?

Comment: The block is complete when the next line of code is reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` is not an asynchronous method. It runs synchronously. So, it won't proceed to the next line until the enumeration is done.

You're probably used to seeing blocks in conjunction with completion handlers for asynchronous requests (e.g. `sendAsynchronousRequest`). But in this case, the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` is just a mechanism to efficiently enumerate through a collection (see [Blocks Can Simplify Enumeration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW5) in the *Programming with Objective-C* guide). And it does this synchronously.